# confusing question of maximum possible weight of a subsequence

Tags: algorithm, logic, dynamic-programming, subsequence

> The weight of a sequence a0, a1, …, an-1 of real numbers is defined as
> a0+a1/2+…+ aa-1/2n-1. A subsequence of a sequence is obtained by
> deleting some elements from the sequence, keeping the order of the
> remaining elements the same. Let X denote the maximum possible weight
> of a subsequence of a0, a1, …,an-1 and Y the maximum possible weight
> of a subsequence of a1, a2, …,an-1. Then X is equal to (A) max(Y,
> a0+Y) (B) max(Y, a0+Y/2) (C) max(Y, a0+2Y) (D) a0+Y/2
>
> Answer: (B)
>
> Explanation: Using concepts of Dynamic Programming, to find the
> maximum possible weight of a subsequence of X, we will have two
> alternatives:
>
> 1. Do not include a0 in the subsequence: then the maximum possible weight will be equal to maximum possible weight of a subsequence of
>    {a1, a2,….an} which is represented by Y
> 2. Include a0: then maximum possible weight will be equal to a0 + (each number picked in Y will get divided by 2) a0 + Y/2. Here you can
>    note that Y will itself pick optimal subsequence to maximize the
>    weight.
>
> Final answer will be Max(Case1, Case2) i.e. Max(Y, a0 + Y/2). Hence
> B).

Why is the 2nd alternative `Y/2` using Dynamic programming?

As per my understanding, the alternatives are:

1. without a0,
   = the maximum possible weight of a subsequence of `a1, a2, …,an-1 = Y`
2. with a0,
   = a0 + the maximum possible weight of a subsequence of `a1, a2, …,an-1 = a0 + Y`  (but in above explaination it takes `Y/2`.  Why?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `a0`, the subsequence sum is

```
Y = a1 + a2/2 + a3/4 ....
```

With `a0` included, the sum becomes

```
a0 + a1/2 + a2/4 + a3/8 ... = a0 + [1/2 * (a1 + a2/2 + a3/4 ...)] = a0 + Y/2
```

So the correct answer would be option `B`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the question:

the weight of the subsequence `a0, a1, a2,..., an-1`
is:

```
X = a0 + a1/2 + a2/4 .... + an-1/2^(n-1)
```

and, the weight of the subsequence (with `a0` not included) `a1, a2, a3,..., an-1`
is:

```
Y =  a1 + a2/2 .... + an-1/2^(n-2)
```

Now, to get `X` from `Y`we can observe that:

```
X = a0 + a1/2 + a2/4 .... + an-1/2^(n-1)
=> X = a0 + (a1/2 + a2/4 .... + an-1/2^(n-1))
=> X = a0 + 1/2(a1 + a2/2 .... + an-1/2^(n-2))
=> X = a0 + 1/2(Y)
```

Now, applying Dynamic Programming, the max weight of the subsequence `a0, a1, a2,..., an-1` will be `max(Y, X) = max(Y, a0 + Y/2)`
Hence option `B` is correct.

Comment: Well explain, Thanks Souvik.